# antLR parser matches too many characters

Tags: java, antlr, lexer

I have grammar for my language. Here part of it

```
myAlias: (project_id '.' )? t_name;

project_id: DIGIT ;

DIGIT :  '0'..'9';
```

Now when debugging the parser for input string

```
someText 1.myName
```

I can see that parser matches '1.' and not '1' as I expect in digit. This cause parse error further in code.

How can I avoid such behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This must be because of the default *greediness* of the lexer.
There are some examples on how to handle it [here](http://meri-stuff.blogspot.sg/2011/09/antlr-tutorial-expression-language.html).

You could use a `fragment` to have the lexer not match it as a token by itself if I am not mistaken. It would look something like this:

```
fragment DIGIT = ('0'..'9')
fragment PROJECT_ID: DIGIT '.';
myAlias: PROJECT_ID? t_name;
```